# What are the pre-requisite for Xamarin test recorder in Windows?

Tags: xamarin-test-cloud, xamarin.windows

Currently my system has  Windows 8.1, and Visual Studio 2015. Can I install xamarin test recorder in Windows desktop or not? If yes then what else I need to install Xamarin test recorder? And, process for the same. I have referred some other solutions too but not getting correct solution yet.  Please guide me to install xamarin test recorder. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Currently Xamarin Test Recorder is available for Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise.  There will be an update released soon that will make it available for Visual Studio 2013 Ultimate as well.